# Selection sort recursively in C++

Tags: c++, function, sorting, recursion

I seem to be producing an error with my recursive selection sort function. Any help would be appreciated in fixing this beast.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void selection_sort(int[],int);

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    selection_sort(a,5);
    return 0;
}

void selection_sort(int arr[],int n){
    int max_pos;
    if(n == 0) return;
    int max = *max_element(arr,arr+n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
        if(arr[max] == max){
            max_pos = i;
        }
    }
    swap(arr[max_pos],arr[n-1]);
    selection_sort(arr,n--);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
selection_sort(arr,n--);
```

In the context of your function (as this is the last statement) this is exactly the same as:

```
selection_sort(arr,n);
```

Leading to infinite recursion since `n` is not modified in the function.  What you probably want is this:

```
selection_sort(arr,n-1);
```

Also, this is wrong:

```
if (arr[max] == max)
```

You want the index to be `i`, not `max`.

```
if (arr[i] == max)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious that this statement

```
if(arr[max] == max){
```

is invalid. There is no any sense to use the maximum element as the index. I think you meant the following

```
int *max = max_element(arr,arr+n);
iter_swap( max, arr + n - 1 );
```

Comment: Also as it was pointed already you shall use selection_sort(arr, --n);